# Interpretation of probability density of a variable from joint density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The joint probability density is $ f(x,y)$

The probability density of X from the joint density is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{A} f(x,y)dxdy$$

$$f_X(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(X=x,y)dy$$

$$ \implies P(X\in A)=\int_{A} f_X(x)dx$$

Can someone explain how to **graphically** interpret the last expression when a joint distribution is given?

Comment: It will be helpful if you put limits on the integration. Distributions aren't indefinite integrals

Comment: Thanks.I have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphically, if the distribution is a massive shape described by the supports of $X,Y$, and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the shape's density of at point $(x,y)$, then $f_X(x)$ is the measure of the contribution of shape's mass by the crossection at $X=x$.   "Adding"(ie integrating) these contributions in the range $X\in A$ gives the mass of that section of the shape.

Assuming that the joint, marginal, and conditional probability density functions are all well defined for the distributions of the real-valued continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$:
$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(X\in A) & =\mathsf P(X\in A ~\cap~ Y\in\Bbb R)
\\ &= \iint_{\Bbb R\times A} f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)~\mathsf d (y,x)
\\ &= \int_A\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)~\mathsf d y~\mathsf d x
\\ &=\int_A f_{\small X}(x)\left(\int_\Bbb R f_{\small Y\mid X{=}x}(y)~\mathsf d y\right)~\mathsf d x
\\ &= \int_A f_{\small X}(x)~\mathsf d x
\end{split}$$

This is basically just the Law of Total Probability in action. For discrete integer valued random variables you would have the analogous:
$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(X\in A) & =\mathsf P(X\in A ~\cap~ Y\in\Bbb Z)
\\ &= \mathop{\sum\!\!\sum}_{(y,x)\in\Bbb Z\times A} \mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)
\\ &= \sum_{x\in A} \sum_{y\in \Bbb Z} \mathsf P(X=x)~\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)
\\ &= \sum_{x\in A} \mathsf P(X=x)\sum_{y\in \Bbb Z}\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x)
\\ &= \sum_{x\in A} \mathsf P(X=x)
\end{split}$$

Comment: $$f_X(x)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(X=x,y)dy$$ This expression tells us that at a cross section X=x, we integrate over y to obtain $f_X(x)$. This gives the mass at X=x, as mentioned by you. Now $f_X(x)$ is integrated over all x's to obtain P(X). But, I am not able to intuitively understand how the below expression is 1. $$\int_\Bbb R f_{\small Y\mid X{=}x}(y)~\mathsf d y$$ Could you please explain?

Comment: $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$ is a conditional *probability density function*, and as such its integral over the domain equals $1$.  @Natasha

Comment: I am still not able to graphically relate these two ways of expressing the probability density of x(the original post and what you have mentioned), how it comes out to be one and the same. When conditional density is used we are scaling each value at the cross section by the mass of the cross-section so that the area sums to 1. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Could you please explain whether the integral over the marginal density of x , when the limit of x is from -$\infty$ to $+\infty$ instead of x$\in$A, is equal to 1@Graham Kemp

Comment: @Natasha Yes, it is a probability density function.